# Twitter API - retweet text modification

Tags: api, twitter

Does anyone know whether it is possible to append additional text onto a retweet using the Twitter API?
What I want to achieve is to be able to take
  @bob Hello Sally!
and retweet it as
  @mike RT @bob Hello Sally! Yo Bob, why the desperation?

The API doc seems to indicate that it is not possible, but that seems incredibly short sighted.
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-retweet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that are looking for an easy way how to implement a RETWEET button, check this out.

I was searching on Google how to install a RETWEET button and luckily I bumped into this article and the link to twitter REST API.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-retweet

It was pure lucky, because the original question was related to another issue, not exactly oriented to those were looking for an easy and simple retweet button or link.

So I decided to  replay this article to help people searching and finding a simple piece of code how to retweet a tweet in a simple link, check this out.

https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=210743023305371648

The method provided by Twitter API REST is pretty similar to the twitter intent, but based on an existent tweet ID.

You just need to change the tweet_id for the specific tweet you want to retweet and style your own retweet button.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you append text it is a sort of unofficial retweet, it is like copy and pasting on the twitter website and adding RT. If you use the API method it is like if you hit the retweet button on the twitter website. You cannot append text using the API method.

So the way you have to do it is just send out a normal tweet with [your text RT @username: retweet text]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I'm currently doing (the RT etc) but the result is then not recognized/shown as an 'official' retweet. If that is how it is then fine, but I think that the API would be much better if it could handle 'value add' text.